# Dynamic T-SQL - Appending parameterized subqueries to a temporary aggregate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

The schema of this database is odd; all of the data is broken up by data type and stored in respective tables. When a 'table' needs to be accessed, it needs to be stitched together, fields by table id, values by field id. It's slow and has been largely been taken care of by third party spaghetti scripts.

I have some tables formatted like so:

dbo.TagSource:

```
TagSourceId | Table Name | ...
------------------------------------
01            Table 1
02            Table 2
```

dbo.Tag:

```
TagId | TagSourceId | Field Name | RawTableName | ...
------------------------------------------------------
11      01            Name         dbo.StringValue
12      01            Age          dbo.IntegerValue
13      01            Balance      dbo.DecimalValue
14      01            Document     dbo.FileValue
15      02            Name         ExternalTable1
16      02            Height       ExternalTable1
17      02            Occupation   ExternalTable2
```

dbo.[String/Integer/Decimal/File/...]Value tables:

```
ValueId | TagId | Value
-------------------------------
101       11      John Smith
102       11      Jane Smith
103       11      John Doe 
104       11      Jane Doe
105       11      Thanos
```

**GOAL:** To create a TSQL query script (stored procedure/function/view) that given a TagSourceID as a parameter/declared variable, returns the corresponding table. Eventually, this will be used to create views until I have the bandwidth to gut and replace this DB schema.

**What is the optimal way to go about this?** It's challenging since the number of fields in each table is dynamic and the column definitions are unknown.

**Attempts:**
I have tried to use temporary tables to hold my aggregate data and the data to be appended, but soon found that since the column definitions have to be predefined I had to resort to an awkward juggling of data between temporary tables. Seems sub-optimal, even if it worked, which it doesn't.

Logic:

```
BEGIN LOOP
#B = #A Join (Select value From dbo...Value Table...)
Drop Table #A
#A = #B
Drop Table #B
END
```

Script: 
Returns error `There is already an object named '#ResultSet' in the database.` even though I've explicitly `DROP TABLE #ResultSet` the line before the error line.

```
--*** DECLARATION ***
USE [DB_Arc];
GO

-- ***************
-- Target Table Id
DECLARE @TagSourceID INT = 130;
-- ***************

-- Temporary Tables - DROP IF EXIST
-- #TempA
IF OBJECT_ID(N'#ResultSet') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ResultSet;
CREATE TABLE dbo.#ResultSet (
    DateTime DATETIME,
    GroupID NVARCHAR(50)
);
-- #TempB
IF OBJECT_ID(N'#JoinSet') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JoinSet;
CREATE TABLE dbo.#JoinSet (
    DateTime DATETIME,
    GroupID NVARCHAR(50)
);

-- Target Fields - Iterator
DECLARE field_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Id, Name, RawTableName
FROM dbo.[Tag]
WHERE TagSourceId = @TagSourceID
AND Name NOT IN ('DateTime','GroupId')
AND TagTypeId NOT IN (6,7)
ORDER BY Id;

-- Local Variables
DECLARE @TagId bigint, @TagName nvarchar(250), @RawTableName nvarchar(250)

OPEN field_cursor;

-- Initial first fetch and store
FETCH NEXT FROM field_cursor
INTO @Tag, @TagName, @RawTableName;

-- Verify that the table where the values are stored is not external.
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @RawTableName)
BEGIN --IF BLOCK
    -- Check @@FETCH_STATUS for any other rows to fetch
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    -- Loop through each field/column...
    BEGIN --LOOP START
        -- full outer join values from rawtables to ResultSet

        -- #TempB = #TempA Join (Select value From dbo...Value Table...)
        DECLARE @field nvarchar(500);
        SET @field = 
        N'SELECT a.*, b.value AS ' + QuoteName(@TagName) +
        N'INTO #JoinSet
          FROM #ResultSet a
          FULL OUTER JOIN ( 
            SELECT
                CONVERT(datetime2, [DateTime], 1) as DateTime,
                [GroupId],
                [Value]
            FROM dbo.' + QuoteName(@RawTableName) +
            N'WHERE TagId = ' + QuoteName(@TagId) + N'AND 
            IsDeleted=0 ) b
          ON a.DateTime = b.DateTime AND a.GroupId = b.GroupId
        ';
        EXEC sp_executesql @field;

        -- DROP TABLE #TempA
        IF OBJECT_ID(N'#ResultSet') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ResultSet
        -- #TempA = #TempB
        -- ***** ERROR BLOCK START *****
        -- Returns 'There is already an object named '#ResultSet' in the database.'
        SELECT *
        INTO #ResultSet
        FROM #JoinSet;
        -- ***** ERROR BLOCK END *****
        -- DROP TABLE #TempB
        DROP TABLE #JoinSet;


        -- Iterate values to next field
        FETCH NEXT FROM field_cursor
        INTO @Tag, @TagName, @RawTableName;
    END --LOOP END

END --IF BLOCK END

CLOSE field_cursor;
DEALLOCATE field_cursor;

SELECT * FROM #ResultSet;
DROP TABLE #ResultSet;

GO
```

I have also been looking into creating a recursive procedure/function to handle this, but I'm having trouble using the cursor as a recursive condition, and table variables/temp tables with static column definitions are still an issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have questions about the purpose of this script, or any general suggestions, I would very much like to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Three issues in the script-

1. There should have Sync between Column name and Number of column between #Temporary table and the row returning from the dynamic script that is
   from "SELECT a.*, b.value AS..........".
2. No need to create the second #Temporary table (#JoinSet) as we can directly insert in the #ResultSet table.
3. Script "SELECT * INTO #Temp......" always try to create the Temporary table where as the table is already created. We need to change the script instead to
   something like "INSERT INTO #ResultSet SELECT a.*,b.value.........".

Comment: I could, but to make matters worse, there are " tables " in the database whose values are NOT stored in in the datatype tables. Instead the data resides externally, however the record of the table and it's fields are stored for reference inline with the tables that are actually stored in the db. So before I iterate through the fields, I check to see if the source table is a real datatype table or a "pseudo-reference" to an external table.

Comment: This whole design is a mess. Eventually when I have the bandwidth, I am going to migrate the data over to a cleaner schema. But in the mean time, I need a way to support the existing systems that rely on this database.

Comment: WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 is basically works like a while loop. So if you keep the table exists checking outside the while loop and table exists return FALSE, the loop will never go forward and fall in a never ending situation. As a result, I feel you should make changes in order of logic you set.

Comment: Another good option is to check the table really exists or not with the cursor script. That is something like joining the dbo.[Tag] table with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and select tables those are really exists.

Comment: The idea is that if the table does not exist, the loop is skipped, and the script closes the cursors and dumps the temp tables. If the source tables do not exist, I shouldn't loop through the fields as the values are inaccessible. So I don't quite understand why the WHILE loop inside the if block would be evaluated if IF EXISTS returns false.

Comment: If you keep the IF EXISTS checking outside the WHILE Loop, for certain case when IF EXISTS will return FALSE, This will not allow the LOOP to execute and as a result data will not move to the next row and will remain on the same row. So IF EXISTS will run for the same row and table name again and will return false again. Suggested CURSOR select statement added in the answer section. You can try that and let me know the issue is solved or now.

Comment: I appreciate the attention you've committed to my problem, but I don't believe you understand the purpose of the IF EXISTS statement. When I evaluate the first row (first field), I am essentially checking to see if the table data is stored externally, or within this database. If `rawtablename` is NOT found in the `information schema.tables`, then I do not want to move the cursor to the next row because the table is external, and none of the fields are located in this DB. **The If Exist statement is not within a loop, so I'm not evaluating the same row again.** I close out the cursor and end.

Comment: Yes probably there are some gap in the understanding. But my feeling about the cursor select script that it should return multiple rows as if it return only one row and you need some actions to take based on table available or not - basically the CURSOR is then not required. But my concern if there multiple rows return by the CURSOR select statement, then its a requirement to move forward one by one row. And if the first row return false, your designed logic will not allow the cursor to move to the next row. But still, May be I am wrong with my understanding :(

Comment: For the sake of brevity, I implemented your suggestion and placed the if exists statement within the loop, and my issue persists. I'm not sure how you've deduced that the placement of the if statement relates to a compile error.

Comment: That's really bad luck @ssoong :(

Comment: How many rows will be returned by your query - FOR SELECT Id, Name, RawTableName
    FROM dbo.[Tag]
    WHERE TagSourceId = @TagSourceID
          AND Name NOT IN('DateTime', 'GroupId')
    AND TagTypeId NOT IN(6, 7)
    ORDER BY Id;

Comment: The cursor is to iterate over multiple "columns". Each row, representing a column of the table, has a `rawtablename` which points to the db where the values are stored on `TagID`, and a 'tagsourceid' which points to the "table" associated to these fields.

Before I iterate over these fields with the cursor, I check the first field to identify if the `tagsourceid` table is sourced in this DB, or externally. If it is sourced externally, then all corresponding rows of the cursor are also external fields. If it is sourced in this db, then I iterate through the rest of the rows.

Comment: It depends on how many fields are in the table I am building. Definitely multiple. But if the table is external, I do not want to iterate over the rest of the rows because the data is all external.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193280/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-ssoong).